# Erro ao Fazer o CodeFirst no EnityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, microsoft

Esse é o erro que está acontecendo:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll Additional information: O
>   inicializador de tipo de 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig'
>   acionou uma exceção.

Esse é meu App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProdutoDb" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=ProdutoDb;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

E esse é meu contexto:

```
using Domain;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;    

namespace Data
{
    public class ProdutoDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ProdutoDbContext() : base("name=ProdutoDb")
        {
            //Verifica se a base de Dados existe, e se não existir ele cria.
           Database.SetInitializer<ProdutoDbContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ProdutoDbContext>());
           Database.Initialize(false);
        }           

        public DbSet<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Loja> Lojas { get; set; }           

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TAG configSections está no lugar errado, ela deve ser única e ser a primeira do arquivo de configurações, ou seja, tem que mover ela para antes do connectionStrings.